# Windowing functions in Dataflow and Big Query

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataflow

I am looking at analysing streaming data (web events).

Is there a good rule of thumb to help me determine if I should

1. Perform Grouping and Aggregation in Dataflow and write the output

or

2. Use Dataflow to stream into Big Query and possibly use a range decorator to limit data / use a windowing function for partitions and aggregate via SQL.

Looking at the examples in the documentation and this article
https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/blog/dataflow-beam-and-spark-comparison

Classic Batch Programming, Hourly Team Scores, All-time User Scores, User Behaviour Analysis feel like they are straightforward to create via SQL (given `"created"` and `"write"` timestamps are recorded)

The Spam filtering example I can see the limitations to using BQ if this applied on a per-event streaming basis).

The semantics of Dataflow seem to overlap in terms of GroupBy, Join, Combine, Windowing as well as BQ supporting streaming inserts with availability in seconds, well short enough for hour level aggregation.

Is there something fundamental I have not understood? Or is there a case that streaming into BigQuery and then querying will start to become unreliable?

Thank you

Chris

(Apologies if this question is a bit vague - happy to be redirected to a better place to ask)

Answer (score 3):

Whether one chooses to perform grouping and aggregation in Dataflow or using BigQuery operations (after having ingested data using Dataflow) is something that depends on the application logic and on what consumes the output.  For example, sessions and sliding windows are both hard to express in SQL; while Dataflow supports arbitrary processing such as triggered estimates.  Another thing to consider is that it may be easier to express the computation logic using an imperative programming language instead of using SQL.

Comment: Thank you - I get the strong impression that the differences are going to come with experience, we are just starting our migration to a streaming architecture. I would add that, in my experience, sessions and sliding windows are very easy to express in SQL using Window Functions bounded with a `{ROWS | RANGE}` or range clause, which is where some of my confusion stems from. We already have split testing and variable weighted attribution implemented this way.

Answer (score 1):

Below, not necessarily answers your exact question, but rather adds yet another aspect to consider:
1.  If you are building process that supposed to power your infrastructure – dataflow might be a good choice. Of course you bound to your tech team resources.
2.  In case if you plan for ad-hocs and self-serve type of activity by non-tech personnel (of course tech personnel is not excluded here also) – you can focus on employing BigQuery’s query features (including windowing functions) and make sure you have good real working examples that rest of your company can use as a template to start leveraging power of BigQuery and GCP in general. This proved to work great! Domain experts now can answer their questions (like you enlisted in your  question) by themselves w/o having tech people in between. Quality and Timing much better in this scenario!